# Getting data from one table to another table using join

Tags: sql, database

I have a table name "a"

```
 Id   name
 1    abc
 2    xyz
 3    mmm
 4    xxx
```

and Other table name is "b"

```
  Id    suId
   3     2
   3     1
```

My requirement is get detail from "a" table from "b" table where id=3. Any help?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: from B where Id=3 get information about all suId into table "a"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.Id, a.name, b.Id, b.suId FROM b JOIN a ON b.suId = a.Id WHERE b.Id = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

I wont recommend join for this kind of scenarios(you want all details from Table A whose ids are in Table B suId column, where Table B id should be 3., Its bad English but hope you got me and may be i got you too.)

```
SELECT a.name FROM a
WHERE 
a.id IN(SELECT b.suId FROM b WHERE b.id = 3);
```

If you want to use join only then,

```
SELECT a.name FROM a,b
WHERE a.id = b.suId
AND
b.id = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

```
SELECT a.Id,a.name FROM a,b
WHERE a.Id=b.suId AND b.Id=3
```

It will give you the result:

```
Id    Name
1     abc
2     xyz
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f6924/1)

Answer (score 0):

This should get the job done:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a a JOIN table_b b ON b.suId = a.Id WHERE b.Id = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...You can try different JOIN clauses like `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or just simply `JOIN` etc. You will get different number of rows depending on field connections from 1 table to the other.

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM a T1
INNER JOIN b T2
ON T1.Id = T2.Id
WHERE T1.Id='3'
```